# Bulk Insertion on Android device

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert

I want to bulk insert about 700 records into the Android database on my next upgrade.  What's the most efficient way to do this?  From various posts, I know that if I use `Insert` statements, I should wrap them in a transaction.  There's also a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887119/populate-android-database-from-csv-file) about using your own database, but I need this data to go into my app's standard Android database.  Note that this would only be done once per device.

Some ideas:

1. Put a bunch of SQL statements in a file, read them in a line at a time, and exec the SQL.
2. Put the data in a CSV file, or JSON, or YAML, or XML, or whatever.  Read a line at a time and do `db.insert()`.
3. Figure out how to do an import and do a single import of the entire file.
4. Make a sqlite database containing all the records, copy that onto the Android device, and somehow merge the two databases.
5. [EDIT] Put all the SQL statements in a single file in res/values as one big string.  Then read them a line at a time and exec the SQL.

What's the best way?  Are there other ways to load data?  Are 3 and 4 even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is any feasible way to accomplish #3 or #4 on your list.

Of the other solutions you list two that have the datafile contain direct SQL, and the other has the data in a non-SQL format.

All three would work just fine, but the latter suggestion of grabbing the data from a formatted file and building the SQL yourself seems the cleanest. If true batch update capability is added at a later date your datafile is still usable, or at least easily processable into a usable form. Also, creation of the datafile is more straightforward and less error prone. Finally, having the "raw" data would allow import into other data-store formats.

In any case, you should (as you mentioned) wrap the groups of inserts into transactions to avoid the per-row transaction journal creation.

Answer (score 98):

Normally, each time `db.insert()` is used, SQLite creates a transaction (and resulting journal file in the filesystem), which slows things down.

If you use `db.beginTransaction()` and `db.endTransaction()` SQLite creates only a single journal file on the filesystem and then commits all the inserts at the same time, dramatically speeding things up.

Here is some pseudo code from: [Batch insert to SQLite database on Android](http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html)

```
try
{
  db.beginTransaction();

  for each record in the list
  {
    do_some_processing();

    if (line represent a valid entry)
    {
      db.insert(SOME_TABLE, null, SOME_VALUE);
    }

    some_other_processing();
  }

  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (SQLException e) {}
finally
{
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

If you wish to abort a transaction due to an unexpected error or something, simply `db.endTransaction()` without first setting the transaction as successful (`db.setTransactionSuccessful()`).

Another useful method is to use `db.inTransaction()` (returns `true` or `false`) to determine if you are currently in the middle of a transaction.

[Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: For more Code Reference: [Batch insert to SQLite database on Android](http://notes.theorbis.net/2010/02/batch-insert-to-sqlite-on-android.html)

Comment: Tried to fix typo in `db.endTransaction()` but it is too small an edit

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was importing about 50 csv files with thousands of records and it would take several hours to complete when done by reading a line from csv and inserting it in the database. With db.beginTransaction() it only took a few seconds! Thanks!

Comment: Rolled back to r4. r5 and r6 were unnecessary - the typo was already fixed.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, per the linked example and the documentation, `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` must be called.  `db.endTransaction()` is already called in the finally block.

Comment: database got locked

Answer (score 34):

I've found that for bulk insertions, the (apparently little-used) [DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html) class is several times faster than using `SQLiteDatabase.insert`.

Two other optimizations also helped with my app's performance, though they may not be appropriate in all cases:

- Don't `bind` values that are empty or `null`.
- If you can be **certain** that it's safe to do it, temporarily turning off the database's internal locking can also help performance.

I have a [blog post](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/) with more details.

Comment: Thanks! This optimization increased importing of a bunch of records by 2x.

Comment: I read the blog, and the comments. Both provided details enough insert all my data within a couple of seconds. Many times better than several minutes.

Comment: Now that `InsertHelper` is deprecated, we are forced to use `SQLiteStatement` ?

Comment: Until now, I hadn't realized that `InsertHelper` is deprecated -- but I'm not surprised. `SQLiteStatement` may be as good a solution as any. I'll try to look into this some more in my Copious Spare Time™ :-)

Comment: For the record: This class was deprecated in API level 17.
Use SQLiteStatement instead.

Comment: [Bulk insert with `SQLiteStatement`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344928/1276636)

Answer (score 10):

This example below will work perfectly

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PRODUCT_LIST
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
        db.beginTransaction();
        for(int idx=0; idx < Produc_List.size(); idx++) {
            statement.clearBindings();
            statement.bindLong(1, Produc_List.get(idx).getProduct_id());
            statement.bindLong(2,  Produc_List.get(idx).getCategory_id());
            statement.bindString(3, Produc_List.get(idx).getName());
//            statement.bindString(4, Produc_List.get(idx).getBrand());
            statement.bindString(5, Produc_List.get(idx).getPrice());
            //statement.bindString(6, Produc_List.get(idx).getDiscPrice());
            statement.bindString(7, Produc_List.get(idx).getImage());
            statement.bindLong(8, Produc_List.get(idx).getLanguage_id());
            statement.bindLong(9, Produc_List.get(idx).getPl_rank());
            statement.execute();

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, my solution for this it kind of weird but works fine...
I compile a large sum of data and insert it in one go (bulk insert?)

I use the `db.execSQL(Query)` command and I build the "Query" with the following statement...

```
INSERT INTO yourtable SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'data1','data2'.... UNION
    SELECT 'data1','data2'.... UNION
    SELECT 'data1','data2'.... UNION
    .
    .
    .
    SELECT 'data1','data2'....
)
```

The only problem is the building of the query which can be kind of messy.
I hope it helps

Comment: Cool.  What a great creative solution.  Sounds like it would be pretty fast.  Is it?

Comment: It would be so fast with StringBuilder class.

Comment: @Andrew Prat...
What is the maximum limit for UNION. for me by this union operation i can able insert 500 record in one insert statement . if i want to inset 5000 record in one statement. it will be possible? if yes then how?