# How to store bulk records into sqlite database in android?

Tags: android

I am working on quiz application and need to store 3000 questions with 5 options and correct answer. So how **to store bulk records into my sqlite database** in **android**. How can I do that. I had searched in google but I didnt find the exact solution for that. Any help regarding this will be thankful...

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860008/bulk-insertion-on-android-device/4464045#4464045

Comment: Do you want to use db with inserted data or you want to insert from program?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but insertion of rows in SQLite is efficient if you make use of transactions and prepared statements.