# Inserting rows in Sqlite slow

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am attempting to insert rows into a SQLite DB. It takes 7 seconds to insert 130 rows, this seems slow to me.

Table definition is :

```
    sd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + V2VocabsTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" 
            + V2VocabsTable.ID   + " VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY ," 
            + V2VocabsTable.NAME    + " VARCHAR(255), " 
            + V2VocabsTable.LOADED  + " VARCHAR(1) " 
            + ");"
            );
```

To insert a row I use the following code :

```
public void addTableStatus(String tableId, String name) {

    Log.d("DB","Before Insert");

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(V2VocabsTable.ID, "Table " + tableId);
    cv.put(V2VocabsTable.NAME, name);
    cv.put(V2VocabsTable.LOADED, "NO");
    SQLiteDatabase sd = getWritableDatabase();
    long result = sd.insert(V2VocabsTable.TABLE_NAME,   null, cv);

    Log.d("DB","After Insert :: " + result);
    }
```

Times in the log file are :

```
 12-17 23:00:11.445: D/SQLDB(25384): Init
 12-17 23:00:11.455: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:11.505: D/SQLDB(25384): Open
 12-17 23:00:11.895: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 1
 12-17 23:00:11.895: D/DB(25384): 0001 :: AdministrativeSex-v1.0.xml
 12-17 23:00:11.895: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:11.965: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 2
 12-17 23:00:11.965: D/DB(25384): 0002 :: MaritalStatus-v1.0.xml
 12-17 23:00:11.965: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:12.005: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 3
 12-17 23:00:12.005: D/DB(25384): 0004 :: PatientClass-v1.0.xml
 12-17 23:00:12.005: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:12.145: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 4

 12-17 23:00:18.815: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:18.865: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 131
 12-17 23:00:18.865: D/DB(25384): ZU057 :: LocationHiding-v1.0.xml
 12-17 23:00:18.865: D/DB(25384): Before Insert
 12-17 23:00:18.925: D/DB(25384): After Insert :: 132
```

This seems excessively slow to me, what could be slowing it down?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are calling `getWritableDatabase()` for each insertion, but the answers here may interest you: [Bulk Insertion on Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3860008/1267661).

Comment: Use Traceview to determine specifically where performance issues lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataBase openWithTrans() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DataBaseHelper(ourContext, DATABASE_NAME,
            DATABASE_LOCATION);
    db = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    return this;
}

public void closeWithTrans() {
    try {

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

        db.endTransaction();
        Debug.debugMsg("end trans successful");
        db.close();
        Debug.debugMsg("close db successful");
        if (ourHelper != null) {
            ourHelper.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The above code will will enable you to do transaction. In transcation mode you should be able to increase your speed up by a lot. And as comment pointed out, you start transaction then insert your x number of rows then close it.

Comment: The important thing is to use *one* transaction for all 130 inserts.

Comment: This was exactly what was required. I placed all of the inserts within one transactions and the 130 inserts all happened within 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

DB operations can be very slow, because of IPC involved, and the SD card access time, but I haven't measured it. But instead of doing hundreds of inserts, you can do a bulkInsert or applyBatch. Are you planning to investigate why it is slow or looking for a faster approach?

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative, you can keep build-ready database file in assest and hard copy/write under /data/data/XX/database.

It's good for one shot Installs.