# caching large amount of data in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, data-caching

I have some technical issue and not having much understandings about it. Please guide me. I actually have to cache large amount of data (including images and texts) in android after getting it from a central server. The data will be added and deleted in a sequence i.e. only that data will be cached/saved that user needs at a time. The data, that will be cached consists of about 80 images plus related text at a time (in worst case). So I think I should use sqlite db here to cache it. Is it a better option here as for as performance and space is concerned?? Or any other is there

Regards

No one else having idea about it,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, save them directly to some location, display all the pictures using any view you like( eg. custom listview) and then delete the useless images.

Comment: I can't do this because there are a lot of posts (images + text) in central db and user will get first 20, first time. These 20 will be cached at some useful location and will be displayed one by one. All of these will not be displayed at once.

Comment: than I think you should implement your own idea of using SQLite db. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860008/bulk-insertion-on-android-device) may help you.