# How to avoid app failure against large database manipulation

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing an android application in which I need to download an `JSON` string and save it in `SQlite` database in a specific format (In my perspective, I have no other option to choose any other data-storage). And this is my table-structure:

```
problem_table(pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
              num TEXT, title TEXT, 
              dacu INTEGER, 
              verdict_series TEXT)
```

And at launch I need almost **4200 rows** to be entered into the database table. I am working on emulator and when I launch the app, it works perfectly. But the app seemed to be freeze for a while after database manipulation is begin. Eventually the app manages to insert all the row but take pretty much time. Even at a point it shows the following look:

[image]

So how can I reduce the time-memory complexity or how can I do this in more optimized way or avoid this temporary failure?

N.S. : I didn't check it in any real device yet for lack of my scope. My emulator is using 512 RAM and 48 heap size.

Comment: Emulator is way too slow, don't use emulator to check the time taken to insert these values, try it on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by @Jakobud answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860008/bulk-insertion-on-android-device/7504118#7504118)

**Answer:**
Normally, each time `db.insert()` is used, SQLite creates a transaction (and resulting journal file in the filesystem). If you use `db.beginTransaction()` and `db.endTransaction()` SQLite commits all the inserts at the same time, dramatically speeding things up.

Here is some pseudo code from: Batch insert to SQLite database on Android

```
try
{
  db.beginTransaction();
  for each record in the list
  {
    do_some_processing();
    if (line represent a valid  entry)
    {
      db.insert(SOME_TABLE, null, SOME_VALUE);
    }
    some_other_processing();
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (SQLException e) {}
finally
{
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do your database manipulations in UI thread but in an AsyncTask, Thread, Service or whatever, but not in the UI Thread.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with this async task bescause your error message is displayed only when a long task is made in main thread. Can you give us the code of your asynctask to try to resolve the problem ? Thanks!