# Bulk insert or update record in Sqlite database in Android

Tags: android-sqlite

In my application, i have to insert or updated Bulk of record in SQLite database android,
record size may 3000 or larger,

```
    String query="SELECT * FROM tableName where "+id+" = "+bean.id()+" and "+other_id+" = "+bean.otherID();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery(query , null);
            mCount.moveToFirst();
            row=mCount.getCount();
            mCount.close();
            /**
             * Insert here
             */
            if(row==0){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(key, "value");
                values.put(key, "value");
                db.insert("tableName", null, values);
            }
            /**
             * Updated here
             */
            else{
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(key, "value");
                values.put(key, "value");
                db.update("tableName", values, "id"+" = ? and "+"other_id"+" = ? ", new String[] {bena.id(),bean.otherid});
            }
```

this code is work fine, but take so much time, how to reduce this time, or bulk insert or update record.

Comment: Answered in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/32288474/2866716