# Bulk saving Custom list view in android

Tags: android

I have created a custom list view with 7 fields which has been populated.
some of the fields have been took from local Db and set in list, else are edittexts. in each list row, i have also populated a save button. on that click i am able to save each list row in to local db. But i need to save the complete list in to local db in a single button click. Is it possible ??

My xml, Java class and adapter class is sending along with this.
XML class :

```
            />
<Spinner 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/spnrsangam"
    />

</TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         >

               <TextView 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share Amount"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txtShreAmnt"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
            />
         <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/edttxtShareAmnt"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:inputType="number"
            />

     <TextView 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Deposit Amount"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txtAmnt"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            />
         <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/edttxtDepAmnt"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:inputType="number"
            />

               <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Set"
    android:background="#C5B2D8"
    android:id="@+id/bttn_Show"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            />
     </TableRow> 

 </TableLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Transaction"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- ............. Table heading ............... -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="#1D1DF2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Share No"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Dep No"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Trans Type"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Share Amt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Deposit Amt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Trans_heading_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C5B2D8"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_Trans_sheet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/Trans_List_Height"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- ......................................... -->

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Java Class is : 
                       package com.example.esccocollection;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Sangam_Collection extends Activity {

ListView transview;
Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter adapter;
List<Retrieve_SangamCollection> translist;

EditText transAmnt, remark, dpsitamntset, shareAmtSet;
String str_agent_id2,idpref, str_setdepAmt, str_setShareAmt;
final AccountDBAdapter db = new AccountDBAdapter(this);
Spinner spnr_sangam;
String str_spinner, str_sangam_name;
Context context;
Button bttnset, bttnSave;

 ArrayList<String> sangamnames = new ArrayList<String>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newtransaction_sheet);

    shareAmtSet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttxtShareAmnt);
    dpsitamntset=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttxtDepAmnt);
    bttnset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttn_Show);
    transview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Trans_sheet);

    str_setdepAmt="";
    str_setShareAmt= "";

    bttnset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            str_setdepAmt= dpsitamntset.getText().toString();
            str_setShareAmt= shareAmtSet.getText().toString();
            str_spinner=spnr_sangam.getSelectedItem().toString();

             getsangam2dtls(str_spinner);

        }

        private void getsangam2dtls(String str_spinner) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 try {

                db.open();
            //  String Maxcramnt = db.getTransSheetdetails();

                //Cursor cur = db.getTransSheetdetails(str_spinner);
                Cursor cur = db.getTransnewSheetdetails(str_spinner);
                final String[] arrayAcc = new String[cur.getCount()];

                String[] arrayName = new String[cur.getCount()];
                String[] arrayBalAmnt = new String[cur.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String accArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Acc_Type"));
                    String nameArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Acc_No"));
                    String tamntArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Dep_No"));
                    arrayAcc[i] = accArray.toString();
                    arrayName[i] = nameArray.toString();
                    arrayBalAmnt[i] = tamntArray.toString();
                    i++;
                    db.close();
                }

                if(arrayAcc.length!=0){

                translist = new ArrayList<Retrieve_SangamCollection>();
                for (int m = 0; m <= cur.getCount(); m++) {
                    //Log.e("Cust name", ""+arrayName[m]);  
                    Retrieve_SangamCollection ret = new 
              Retrieve_SangamCollection
          (arrayAcc[m],arrayName[m],arrayBalAmnt[m],str_setShareAmt,
                   str_setdepAmt);
                    translist.add(ret); 
                    listset();
                }               
                }else {
                    transview.setAdapter(null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data to display", 5000).show();
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Trans retlist ", ""+e.getMessage());
        }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        private void listset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                transview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Trans_sheet);
                transview.setAdapter(null);
                adapter = new Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter
             (Sangam_Collection.this,    R.layout.trans_pop_list, translist);
                transview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("tr amount is:", "error..");
            }

            get_list();
        }
    });



    spnr_sangam=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrsangam);
/////------------- to get sangam name from shared pref  -----------------

    SharedPreferences pr_sangam_name=getSharedPreferences("pr_sangam_name", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    str_sangam_name=pr_sangam_name.getString("sangam_name", ""); 

    Log.e("Sangam name in loanform", ""+str_sangam_name);




    sangamnames.add(str_sangam_name);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sangamnames);
    spnr_sangam.setAdapter(adapter1);

/*  
    String[] items = new String[] {"sangam1", "sangam2" };
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    spnr_sangam.setAdapter(adapter1);*/
    //  str_spinner=spnr_sangam.getSelectedItem().toString();
    // String sanagam="sangam1";

        /*db.open();
        String Maxcramnt = db.getTransSheet(sanagam);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Maxcramnt, 5000).show();
        db.open();*/


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spnr_sangam.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // str_spinner=spnr_sangam.getSelectedItem().toString();
             str_spinner=spnr_sangam.getSelectedItem().toString();

             getsangam2dtls(str_spinner);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            // return false;
        }

        private void getsangam2dtls(String str_spinner) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {   

                db.open();
            //  String Maxcramnt = db.getTransSheetdetails();

            //  Cursor cur = db.getTransSheetdetails(str_spinner);
                Cursor cur = db.getTransnewSheetdetails(str_spinner);
                final String[] arrayAcc = new String[cur.getCount()];

                String[] arrayName = new String[cur.getCount()];
                String[] arrayBalAmnt = new String[cur.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String accArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Acc_Type"));
                    String nameArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Acc_No"));
                    String tamntArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Dep_No"));
                    arrayAcc[i] = accArray.toString();
                    arrayName[i] = nameArray.toString();
                    arrayBalAmnt[i] = tamntArray.toString();
                    i++;
                    db.close();
                }

                if(arrayAcc.length!=0){

                translist = new ArrayList<Retrieve_SangamCollection>();
                for (int m = 0; m <= cur.getCount(); m++) {
                //  Log.e("Cust name", ""+arrayBalAmnt[m]); 
                    Retrieve_SangamCollection ret = new Retrieve_SangamCollection(arrayAcc[m], arrayName[m], arrayBalAmnt[m], str_setShareAmt, str_setdepAmt);
                    translist.add(ret); 
                    listset();
                }               
                }else {
                    transview.setAdapter(null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data to display", 5000).show();
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Trans retlist ", ""+e.getMessage());
        }

        }

        private void listset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                transview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_Trans_sheet);
                transview.setAdapter(null);
                adapter = new    
      Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter(Sangam_Collection.this,
                 R.layout.trans_pop_list, translist);
                transview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("tr amount is:", "error..");
            }   
        }

        /*private void getsangam1dtls(String str_spinner) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {


                db.open();
            //  String Maxcramnt = db.getTransSheetdetails();

                Cursor cur = db.getTransSheetdetails(str_spinner);
                //Cursor cur = db.getTransSheetdetails();
                final String[] arrayAcc = new String[cur.getCount()];

                String[] arrayName = new String[cur.getCount()];
                String[] arrayBalAmnt = new String[cur.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String accArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Acc_No"));
                    String nameArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Cust_Name"));
                    String tamntArray = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex("Bal_Amt"));
                    arrayAcc[i] = accArray.toString();
                    arrayName[i] = nameArray.toString();
                    arrayBalAmnt[i] = tamntArray.toString();
                    i++;
                    db.close();
                }

                translist = new ArrayList<retrieveTrans>();
                for (int m = 0; m <= cur.getCount(); m++) {

                    //Log.e("Cust name", ""+arrayName[m]);  
                    retrieveTrans ret = new retrieveTrans(arrayAcc[m], 
    arrayName[m], arrayBalAmnt[m]);
                    translist.add(ret); 
                    listset();
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Trans retlist ", ""+e.getMessage());
        }

                //Cursor cur 

        }*/

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    try {


        transview = getListView();
        transview.setLongClickable(true);
        transview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        transview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on item clicked", 5000).show();

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on item checked statmnt", 5000).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("List work ", ""+e.getMessage());
    }

}
private ListView getListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
protected void get_list() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for(int i = 0;i<=transview.getCount();i++);
    {

    }



}
};
```

this is adapter class

```
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<Retrieve_SangamCollection> ret_arrArrayList;
private List<Retrieve_SangamCollection> ret_translist;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspin;
String time, currntdate, status;
String Maxcramnt, balamount,str_useridpref;
double Mamount, Bamount, actualamnt;
String idpref, str_agent_id2, accno;
int trcheck;
int d = 0;
String tramnt = "", remarks = "";
Context context;

int count;



public Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter(Sangam_Collection sangam_Collection,
        int transListPop, List<Retrieve_SangamCollection> translist) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.ret_translist = translist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(sangam_Collection);
    this.ret_arrArrayList = new ArrayList<Retrieve_SangamCollection>();
    this.ret_arrArrayList.addAll(translist);
    this.context = sangam_Collection;

}


public Custom_SangamCollection_Adapter(Context context2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ret_translist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ret_translist.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView acc_txt, name_txt, balAmnt_txt;
    Spinner trans_spinner;
    EditText transAmnt_edittxt, remarks_edittxt;
    Button save;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int pos, View cv, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        View row = cv;

        int p = pos;
    //  Log.e("position of getview:", "" + p);
        if (cv == null) {

            cv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trans_pop_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.acc_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransAccNo_pop);
            holder.name_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransName_pop);
            holder.balAmnt_txt = (TextView) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTransBalAmnt_pop);

            holder.trans_spinner = (Spinner) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinTrans_Type);

            holder.transAmnt_edittxt = (EditText) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTransAmnt_pop);
            holder.save = (Button) cv.findViewById(R.id.save);

            holder.remarks_edittxt = (EditText) cv
                    .findViewById(R.id.editRemarks_pop);
            cv.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) cv.getTag();
        }

        holder.acc_txt.setText("" + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetAccNo());
        String hari = holder.acc_txt.getText().toString();
        holder.name_txt.setText("" + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetName());
        holder.balAmnt_txt.setText(""
                + ret_translist.get(pos).getRetBalAmnt());
        holder.remarks_edittxt.setText(""+ret_translist.get(pos).getsetdpAmnt());
        holder.transAmnt_edittxt.setText(""+ret_translist.get(pos).getsetShrAmt());

    //  holder.remarks_edittxt.setText("100");

    /* ************* Declaring spinner items ************** */

        String[] items = new String[] { "credit" };
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterspin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        final String haris = holder.name_txt.getText().toString();          

        holder.trans_spinner.setAdapter(adapterspin);

    /* ******************* Save button Click ******************* */

        holder.save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int position = pos;

                final String accno = holder.name_txt.getText().toString();

                final String tramnt = holder.transAmnt_edittxt.getText()
                        .toString();
                String remarks = holder.remarks_edittxt.getText()
                        .toString();
                final String spinner = holder.trans_spinner
                        .getSelectedItem().toString();


                Log.e("accno:", "" + accno);
                Log.e("name :", "" + tramnt);
                Log.e("position:", "" + position);
                Log.e("remark:", "" + remarks);
                Log.e("spinner:", "" + spinner);


                /************* time and date *************/
                // ----------Time----------**
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                time = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                        + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                Log.e("Current Time", " " + time);

                // -----------Date---------**
                Date now = new Date();
                Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                currntdate = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy").format(now);
                Log.e("Date ", " " + currntdate);

    /* **************** Check if all fields are Filled **************** */

                status = new String("y");

                if (tramnt.equals("")) {

                    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),
                            "enter Transaction amount", 5000).show();

                    Log.e("if cndition", " " + tramnt);
                } else if (spinner.equals("Type")) {

                    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),
                            "Select Transaction type", 5000).show();

                    Log.e("if cndition", " " + tramnt);
                }
                else {

                    if (remarks.equals("")) {

                        remarks = "null";
                    }
           /******************** declaration for dbcall *********************/
                    try{      

                          SharedPreferences pr_acc_info=context.
                           getSharedPreferences("pr_acc_info",
             context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                          str_useridpref=pr_acc_info.getString("userid","");
                     //  String   str_brnamepref=pr_acc_info.getString("branchname","");

                          Log.e("userid in custom sangamcollction", ""+str_useridpref);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("", e.toString());
                    }   

                    AccountDBAdapter db = new AccountDBAdapter(context);
                    Sangam_Collection ts = new Sangam_Collection();

                    try {
                        db.open();

                        String accid = db.getAccID(accno);
                        String Maxcramnt = db.getMaxCrAmnt(accno);

                        db.close();

                        Log.e("tramnt", " " + tramnt);

                        Log.e("Mamount", " " + Mamount);


                        actualamnt = 0;


                        String userId = "" + 2;
                        Mamount = Double.parseDouble(Maxcramnt);
                        Bamount = Double.parseDouble(tramnt);
                        Log.e("Mamount", " " + Mamount);
                        if(Bamount<Mamount)
                        {
                            Mamount = Double.parseDouble(Maxcramnt);
                            //Bamount = Double.parseDouble(tramnt);
                            actualamnt = Mamount - Bamount;
                            balamount = "" + actualamnt;
                            db.open();
                            db.update_MaxCrAmnt(balamount, accid);
                            db.close();
                            db.open();

                        db.insertTransactionTable(accid.toString(),
                                currntdate.toString(), spinner.toString(),
                                tramnt.toString(), str_useridpref.toString(),
                                time.toString(), remarks.toString(),
                                status.toString());

                        db.close();
                        holder.save.setText("SAVED");
                        holder.save.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Your Amount Exceeds your Balance", 5000).show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception c) {
        Log.e("adapter error", "" + c.getMessage());
    }
    return cv;

}

}
```

Need your valuable help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can save these values in the database. When you click the save button call a function there that will save the values ...

Comment: and one more thing do you want to also display there data after it is saved ?

Comment: no..data need not to be displayed. but i need to save the entire list data in row wise in a single click.

Comment: yes it can be done. did you tried anything before ?

Comment: yup, clicking save button on each row is working. but saving entire list is problem.

Comment: that is possible only by making the large string and then inserting it at once. or maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860008/bulk-insertion-on-android-device
 but it would slow things down.

Comment: "But i need to save the complete list in to local db in a single button click" what actually do you mean by that?

Comment: all list items should be saved in db .. on a single button click. means data in each row should be saved.

Comment: use CursorAdapter, not BaseAdapter, why do you use BaseAdapter if your data moddel is sqlite database?