# SQLite multiple insert issue

Tags: sqlite, transactions, insert

I'm working with SQLite for my Android application and after some research I figured out how to do multiple insert transactions using the UNION statement.

But this is quite inefficient. From what I see at http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html, and in a lot of other forums, I can speed up the process using the BEGIN - COMMIT statements. But when I use them I get this error:

> Cannot start a transaction within a transaction.

Why? What is the most efficient way of doing multiple insert?

Comment: see if that helps you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8027788/1007273

Answer (score 0):

Which JDBC driver are you using? Is there only one that's built into the Android distribution?

The problem is most likely with [`java.sql.Connection#setAutoCommit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29). If the connection already has *auto-commit* enabled—which you can check with [`Connection#getAutoCommit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit%28%29)—then your JDBC driver is already issuing the SQL commands to start a transaction before your manual attempt to do, which renders your manual command redundant and invalid.

If you're looking to control transaction extent, you need to disable *auto-commit* mode for the `Connection` by calling

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

and then later, after your individual DML statements have all been issued, either commit or roll back the active transaction via [`Connection#commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit%28%29) or [`Connection#rollback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback%28%29).

I have noticed that some JDBC drivers have a hard time coordinating *auto-commit* mode with [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)'s batch-related methods. In particular, [the Xerial JDBC driver](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) and [the Zentus driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) on which it's based both fight against a user controlling the *auto-commit* mode with batch statement execution.