# Exporting a database on the phone to a .csv that can be used on the computer

Tags: android, database, sqlite, export, export-to-csv

I was wondering whether anyone had the code that would allow me to export my database in my app and export it as a .csv. This would then hopefully allow people to open it in Microsoft Office Excel and read their data at any time.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887119/populate-android-database-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 3):

just do 
SELECT * FROM [table];  (into some datastructure)

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

for(y=0; y<=[#rows]; y++){
    for(x=0; x<=[#columns]; x++){
        out.write([field]);
        out.write(",");
    }
    out.write("\n");
}
out.close;
```

Comment: I used this. Just need an out.close(); after the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :
[tutorial](http://bloggerinme.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/android-database-table-export-to-csv-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I can get this to work. I'll give you feedback at a later date when I have it correct.