# Android map route overlay example

Tags: android

does anyone have a tutorial or example of how to use a csv file with comma separated latitude longitude coordinates to draw a route on a map overlay for use in a hill walking application. The csv file is to be stored in the assets folder.

I am new to android development and have been searching high and low with no success to date.

Many thanks in advance.

Many tanks for the comment - I have got to the point where I can draw a path but only every other point, my next question is how do you loop through the csv file to show a continuous path - code below.

```
class WalkOverlay extends Overlay{  

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        // start csv parser        
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("CSV/Mountain Walks/llanberisPath.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                longitude = RowData[0];
                latitude = RowData[1];

                Double lat = new Double(latitude);
                Double lng = new Double(longitude);

                geoPoint1 = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));                                                                                     
            gP1 = geoPoint1;
            gP2 = geoPoint2;

            p1 = new Point();
            p2 = new Point();

                path = new Path();

                Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
            projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
            projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

            path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
            path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);

                }

            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle exception
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply club the three questions below

- [Populate Android Database From CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887119/populate-android-database-from-csv-file)
- [Get and Parse CSV file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360628/get-and-parse-csv-file-in-android)
- [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

:)