# Packaging SQLite DB with my application

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database on my PC. I have imported it into my ***assets*** folder in the project directory. How do I access it from my Android application?

Comment: Please don't give me tutorials on SQLiteOpenHelper ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use my own sqlite database? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387421/how-to-use-my-own-sqlite-database), among others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy it into your database directory (`getDatabasePath()`) using Java I/O. At that point, you can use it like a normal database. It is impossible to use it from within the assets themselves.