# Android SQLite databases

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to have a SQLite database for my android application. Anyone knows how to create a database and add information not going through an application class. Is there some user interfaces allow create a SQLite database, add tables, information and later use in the application.
                           thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html, teaches you all the basic of android app and the guide is using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it with Firefox addon SQLite Manager, and then ship it with your application. Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387421/how-to-use-my-own-sqlite-database/2387818).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good tools are mentioned in answers to [another similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835069/which-sqlite-administration-console-do-you-recommend) question. You can use them to create a new database or edit existing.