# how to use predefined sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use my own sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387421/how-to-use-my-own-sqlite-database)
>   [Full Android Database Helper class for existing SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548533/full-android-database-helper-class-for-existing-sqlite-database)

I am new to android, i have created database using sqlite database browser now i want to use this database in my application so what are the step to do so any example code or any help will be appriciated

Comment: Greg Hewgill i have followed this tutorial http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ but it is not working for me because my database is very big more than 1.2 mb the capacity of assets folder so i am bit concern ? is there any other approch instead of this

Comment: please check this: [Use existing SQLite Database](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+use+existing+sqlite+database)

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions from [this blog](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

It will walk you through all the steps you need to use to get a pre-created db into your app.

**EDIT**

You didn't mention that your db was large in the initial post.  In that case you might want to try [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

I don't see where it says it, but I know I've seen Mark from CommonsWare comment that it will transfer any size file for you.  You zip up the db, put it in your assets/databases folder, and follow their directions to code your db class and you should be good to go.

Comment: yes i am following the same blog but as i have mentioned that my database is big so that is the problem. is there any alternative instead of breaking database into part or keeping into asset folders

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma, updated my answer with something that may be more helpful than my first attempt.  :)