# Stumped on how to call createDatabaseIfNotExists() from How to use my own sqlite database? tutorial

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Trying to use DbUtils class presented here:

[How to use my own sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387421/how-to-use-my-own-sqlite-database)

I am trying to call createDatabaseIfNotExists() when the application starts up with the following code:

```
DbUtils dbu = new DbUtils();
dbu.createDatabaseIfNotExists(this);
```

However the second line has the errors:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "this", delete this token
    - The static method getStaticDb() from the type DbUtils should be accessed in a 
     static way
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Feeling lost, could someone please provide the the code to call createDatabaseIfNotExists().

Comment: becuase all methods inside DbUtils is declared as static then instead of  using class instance to access these methods just access it as `DbUtils.createDatabaseIfNotExists(this); DbUtils.getStaticDb() ,...`

Comment: You need to use the following script AFTER OnCreate() in your main activity:

    try {
   DbUtils.createDatabaseIfNotExists(this);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

This cleared the errors and I successfully compiled my app.